# Why is the pressure of a jet, as it exits, is always the ambient pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Why is it equal to the ambient pressure and not higher?  Why does this constraint exists?

Comment: I don't understand. Add more details.

Comment: @peterh Water from the hose of fire brigade comes at atmospheric pressure, fuel from the injector of a diesel engine comes at the pressure of the combustion chamber, say 80 bar etc etc

Comment: Give a reference for who/what says that the pressure acts as you stated.  Could it be the ambient pressure is the boundary condition *after* exiting versus "as it exits?"

Comment: @BillN You could see it written everywhere, only supersonic jets are excepted. If you disagree with my assumption, please feel free to write your version in an answer

Comment: Surface tension effects due to curvature of jet surface (in the plane normal to its direction of flow) causes uniform increase in pressure (above ambient) inside the jet. But this effect is significant only if the jet diameter is very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case for a subsonic jet exiting the orifice with straight streamlines. Newton's law taken normal to the streamlines stipulates that the pressure gradient normal to the streamline is proportional to the radius of curvature. Since the streamlines are straight, the normal pressure gradient vanishes, meaning the pressure throughout the jet is constant and equal to the pressure at the jet's edge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I find a formulation of the law of Newton that you mention?

Comment: Any undergraduate textbook in fluid mechanics; this is traditionally treated along with the elementary derivation of the Bernoulli equation. Also look at the [Wikipedia article on the Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)), under "Streamline Curvature Theorem".

Comment: So if the jet is expanding in cross-sectional area, there is a pressure gradient, and the central pressure at the exit is different from the central pressure further away from the exit?